# Which all attributes shoud be added to make a button that opens a menu of actions to make it accesible to assistive technology

Tags: accessibility, wcag2.0

[menu iniside table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpaB6.png)

Which all attributes shoud be added to make a button that opens a menu of actions which is placed inside a table to make it accesible to assistive technology.

Tried to add role=menu. Also added aria-expanded, but did not work.

Comment: You don’t mean Ada (the programming language). What about reading the tag info before using it

Comment: Yeah, they didn't read the description of the tag and assumed ada mean Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA) which is often used when people talk about accessibility programming.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Menu Button pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menu-button/) as long as you implement arrow key navigation (up/down) within the menu.

If you want to navigate within your "menu" using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key instead of the up/down arrow keys, then don't use the menu pattern, use the [Disclosure Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/) instead.